# How to make proxy server setting take effect for tortoisehg in Windows?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I set the proxy server in 'global settings' for my tortoisehg in Windows. When I try to connect to bitbucket repositories, the generated command line by tortoisehg was `hg clone --debug-- http://bitbucket.org/<path to repo>`.

The console shows as follows:

```
using http://bitbucket.org/<path to repo>
proxying through http://172.19.6.47:8080
http auth: user <username>, password not set
sending capabilities command
```

I also run wireshark to monitor the traffic. To my surprise the traffic is transferred to bitbucket directly. I thought it should send the packets to the proxy server first. Does it mean that my proxy server does not take effect? What can I do to make it take effect?

Answer (score 4):

Your `mercurial.ini` file should have a section like so:

```
[http_proxy]
host = aproxy.somedomain.com:1234
```

Check that it is present.  Maybe it wasn't saved correctly?

I made a fake entry as above and tried a pull and immediately got a failure to connect to proxy.

Comment: I edited the file with tortoisehg GUI and I confirmed the result correct after I read the generated `mercurial.ini`. But I clearly saw the TCP SYN sent to bitbucket directly, with my proxy setting ignored. And of course I saw a timeout error (`URLError: [Errno 10060] `) since I did not have direct Internet connection. Are you using tortoisehg on Windows? What version of mercurial are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest TortoiseHg 2.4.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The following two webpage have a right answer.

(1) http://d.hatena.ne.jp/falkenhagen/20091007/1254909363

(2) http://www.jameswampler.com/2010/06/10/configure-mercurial-hg-to-use-a-proxy-server/

From the second link, he says:

My laptop is behind our corporate firewall for most of the day, so being able to do an hg push/pull against bitbucket.org fails because it isn’t hitting or proxy server. To setup Mercurial to use a proxy server, edit your hrgc file in the .hg folder of your repository and add this section:

```
[http_proxy]
host = foo.bar:8000
passwd = password
user = username
```

Just change the values to your proxy server hostname and port, username and password.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10834194)

Comment: @DamianKozlak, I have modified the answer, please kindly check it.

Comment: Good, it's much better.